# Documentation for using tor as a proxy

Tags: proxy

I am trying to get some of my own code to make http requests over tor. However, I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Where can I find documentation on connecting to tor as a proxy?

Comment: Tor acts as a SOCKS proxy (on port 9050 by default). You can find an overview of the protocol [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I wasn't really clear with what I was looking for. I want the documentatio.

Answer (score 0):

To make a request over Tor, you need to create a socket to tor's SOCKS proxy port, and then send/receive data on that socket following the [SOCKS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). I don't think that there's any specific Tor documentation about how to write a program that communicates with tor's SOCKS proxy.

Tor's SOCKS support is documented at: "Tor's extensions to the SOCKS protocol" — https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/socks-extensions.txt

If you want an example of how to connect to the SOCKS proxy, a good example might be the source code of torsocks: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git/tree/src/common/socks5.c

Depending on your programming language, there are probably libraries that will take care of the SOCKS stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks, but the tool I am using already supports socks. What I was looking for is answers to questions like: how do I open a tor proxy (without just opening the tor browser). How can I run multiple proxies at the same time? How do I close a tor proxy?